# HTML/CSS dropdown next to button

Tags: html, css

So i have a vertical navbar with dropdowns but everytime i do a dropdown its drops straight down from where it started.
I would like the dropdown menu to appear to the right of the bar.
In the code snippet you wil see what code i'm using now (from w3schools).

I also included an image to beter show what i mean.

[image: Quite a bad drawing but gets the job done]

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/b2nf590b/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could apply `position: absolute;` and a couple simple positioning rules to your `.dropdown-content` CSS like so:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Because your `.dropdown` position is `relative`, we can use `position: absolute;` on its children to position them relative to their parent instead of the entire page.

`left: 100%`; aligns the child's left-edge with the right-edge of its parent, and `top: 0;` aligns it flush along the top.

**Example:**

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can view it here : https://jsfiddle.net/a0dwpbd9/

Comment: I modified this to include embedded runnable code snippets.  This helps to keep the integrity of the solution as the jsfiddle.net link may break in the future.  It also allows easy testing of the solution provided.

Comment: Any idea on how to make it work on this code? https://jsfiddle.net/942utouw/ I tryed to figure it out but i think i'm not getting it

Comment: What is the desired function here?